# Why is my search bar not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to add a search bar to my existing table view...
I have added my searchBar property to my .m file and I have added the searchbar delegate and yet I have no avail. I am new to adding search functions to my code.

here is my header

#import

```
#import "SelectSingleView.h"
#import "SelectMultipleView.h"
#import "AddressBookView.h"
#import "FacebookFriendsView.h"

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@interface PeopleView : UITableViewController <SelectSingleDelegate, SelectMultipleDelegate, AddressBookDelegate, FacebookFriendsDelegate>
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id<PeopleView>delegate;

@end
```

and here is the .m file

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "ProgressHUD.h"

#import "utilities.h"

#import "PeopleView.h"
#import "ProfileView.h"
#import "SelectSingleView.h"
#import "SelectMultipleView.h"
#import "AddressBookView.h"
#import "FacebookFriendsView.h"
#import "NavigationController.h"

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@interface PeopleView()
{
    BOOL skipLoading;
    NSMutableArray *users;
    NSMutableArray *userIds;
    NSMutableArray *sections;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;


@end
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@implementation PeopleView
//@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize searchBar;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    {
        [self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_people"]];
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"People";
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(actionCleanup) name:NOTIFICATION_USER_LOGGED_OUT object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)viewDidLoad
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Friends";

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/256.0) green:(128/256.0) blue:(0/256.0) alpha:(1.0)];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self
                                                                                           action:@selector(actionAdd)];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    userIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   // UIButton *facebookButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    //[facebookButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"gibrlogo.png"];
    //[facebookButton setTitle:@"Facebook Friends" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   // [facebookButton sizeToFit];
    //facebookButton.center = CGPointMake(210.0, 30.0);// for center;
    // Add an action in current code file (i.e. target)
    //[facebookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookButtonPressed:)
    // forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[self.view addSubview:facebookButton];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil)
    {
        if (skipLoading) skipLoading = NO; else [self loadPeople];
    }
    else LoginUser(self);
}

#pragma mark - Backend methods


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)facebookButtonPressed:(UIButton *)facebookButton
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    skipLoading = YES;
    FacebookFriendsView *facebookFriendsView = [[FacebookFriendsView alloc] init];
    facebookFriendsView.delegate = self;
    NavigationController *navController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:facebookFriendsView];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"facebookButton Pressed");
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)loadPeople
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_PEOPLE_CLASS_NAME];
    [query whereKey:PF_PEOPLE_USER1 equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query includeKey:PF_PEOPLE_USER2];
    [query setLimit:1000];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            [users removeAllObjects];
            [userIds removeAllObjects];
            for (PFObject *people in objects)
            {
                PFUser *user = people[PF_PEOPLE_USER2];
                [users addObject:user];
                [userIds addObject:user.objectId];
            }
            [self setObjects:users];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        else [ProgressHUD showError:@"Network error."];
    }];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)searchUsers:(NSString *)search_lower
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_BLOCKED_CLASS_NAME];
    [query1 whereKey:PF_BLOCKED_USER1 equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_USER_CLASS_NAME];
    [query2 whereKey:PF_USER_OBJECTID notEqualTo:[PFUser currentId]];
    [query2 whereKey:PF_USER_OBJECTID doesNotMatchKey:PF_BLOCKED_USERID2 inQuery:query1];
    [query2 whereKey:PF_USER_FULLNAME_LOWER containsString:search_lower];
    [query2 orderByAscending:PF_USER_FULLNAME_LOWER];
    [query2 setLimit:1000];
    [query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil)
         {
             [users removeAllObjects];
             [users addObjectsFromArray:objects];
             [self.tableView reloadData];
         }
         else [ProgressHUD showError:@"Network error."];
     }];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)setObjects:(NSArray *)objects
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    if (sections != nil) [sections removeAllObjects];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NSInteger sectionTitlesCount = [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] count];
    sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:sectionTitlesCount];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<sectionTitlesCount; i++)
    {
        [sections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NSArray *sorted = [objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        PFUser *user1 = (PFUser *)obj1;
        PFUser *user2 = (PFUser *)obj2;
        return [user1[PF_USER_FULLNAME] compare:user2[PF_USER_FULLNAME]];
    }];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (PFUser *object in sorted)
    {
        NSInteger section = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForObject:object collationStringSelector:@selector(fullname)];
        [sections[section] addObject:object];
    }
}

#pragma mark - User actions

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)actionCleanup
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [users removeAllObjects];
    [userIds removeAllObjects];
    [sections removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)actionAdd
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *action1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Search for a Friend" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { [self actionSelectSingle]; }];
    UIAlertAction *action2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Add Friends" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { [self actionSelectMultiple]; }];
    UIAlertAction *action3 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Invite Friends SMS" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { [self actionAddressBook]; }];
    UIAlertAction *action4 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Invite Facebook Friends" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { [self actionFacebookFriends]; }];
    UIAlertAction *action5 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];

    [alert addAction:action1]; [alert addAction:action2]; [alert addAction:action3]; [alert addAction:action4]; [alert addAction:action5];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)actionSelectSingle
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    skipLoading = YES;
    SelectSingleView *selectSingleView = [[SelectSingleView alloc] init];
    selectSingleView.delegate = self;
    NavigationController *navController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:selectSingleView];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - SelectSingleDelegate

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)didSelectSingleUser:(PFUser *)user
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [self addUser:user];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)actionSelectMultiple
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    skipLoading = YES;
    SelectMultipleView *selectMultipleView = [[SelectMultipleView alloc] init];
    selectMultipleView.delegate = self;
    NavigationController *navController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:selectMultipleView];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - SelectMultipleDelegate

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)didSelectMultipleUsers:(NSMutableArray *)users_
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    for (PFUser *user in users_)
    {
        [self addUser:user];
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)actionAddressBook
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    skipLoading = YES;
    AddressBookView *addressBookView = [[AddressBookView alloc] init];
    addressBookView.delegate = self;
    NavigationController *navController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addressBookView];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - AddressBookDelegate

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)didSelectAddressBookUser:(PFUser *)user
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [self addUser:user];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)actionFacebookFriends
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    skipLoading = YES;
    FacebookFriendsView *facebookFriendsView = [[FacebookFriendsView alloc] init];
    facebookFriendsView.delegate = self;
    NavigationController *navController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:facebookFriendsView];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - FacebookFriendsDelegate

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)didSelectFacebookUser:(PFUser *)user
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [self addUser:user];
}

#pragma mark - Helper methods

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)addUser:(PFUser *)user
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    if ([userIds containsObject:user.objectId] == NO)
    {
        PeopleSave([PFUser currentUser], user);
        [users addObject:user];
        [userIds addObject:user.objectId];
        [self setObjects:users];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    return [sections count];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    return [sections[section] count];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    if ([sections[section] count] != 0)
    {
        return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
    }
    else return nil;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSMutableArray *userstemp = sections[indexPath.section];
    PFUser *user = userstemp[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = user[PF_USER_FULLNAME];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user[PF_USER_EMAIL];
    if(cell.detailTextLabel.text == nil){
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Facebook Account";
    }

    return cell;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    return YES;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    NSMutableArray *userstemp = sections[indexPath.section];
    PFUser *user = userstemp[indexPath.row];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PeopleDelete([PFUser currentUser], user);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [users removeObject:user];
    [userIds removeObject:user.objectId];
    [self setObjects:users];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NSMutableArray *userstemp = sections[indexPath.section];
    PFUser *user = userstemp[indexPath.row];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ProfileView *profileView = [[ProfileView alloc] initWith:nil User:user];
    profileView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profileView animated:YES];
}
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    if ([searchText length] > 0)
    {
        [self searchUsers:[searchText lowercaseString]];
    }
    else [self loadPeople];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar_
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [searchBar_ setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar_
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [searchBar_ setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar_
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [self searchBarCancelled];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar_
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [searchBar_ resignFirstResponder];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)searchBarCancelled
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    [self loadPeople];
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you have the `searchBar.delegate` set to your class (either in code or in IB)? The delegate methods won't be called if its not set

Comment: Hmm no I dont... I'm still pretty new with this

Comment: In your viewdidload, set your serchBar.delegate = self;